# Magento 2 - I need to create simple custom report with date range and other column filter (filter should be outside of grid)

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3, custom-reports

I need to create **custom report** which is just like **magento default reports**. I go through the Internet I found this https://github.com/degdigital/magento2-customreports but In this report data is already fetched and they give **column level filter** functionality like this

[image]

I need the **data fetch based on filters**

> For Reference I need simple report like this:

[image]

I hope, you guys got my point, if you have any free extension, git code and your experience please share it

Thanks

Comment: Did you find any solution on this?

Comment: Though I made custom report but I know what I follow is not a best practice. I want a solution for custom report just like Magento Default report.

Comment: Can I start bounty on this question?

Comment: Yes you can if you want

Comment: Hi I am working on same type of reports. I can provide you the extension.

Comment: ok share it if you can but please note I already use this https://github.com/degdigital/magento2-customreports

Comment: Can i send you on skype

Comment: No Share it here so it helps others as well

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I share my working what I do, in order to do this achieve this functionality

This is my collection file, What I do, I store the filter data against admin user wise in custom table and made custom model for that table. Use it during collection loading.

Path should be like: `Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Brandwisereport\Collection.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Brandwisereport;
//use Vendor\Module\Model\TempdataFactory;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{

    /**
     * Define resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Vendor\Module\Model\Brandwisereport', 'Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Brandwisereport');
        $this->_map['fields']['page_id'] = 'main_table.page_id';
        $this->addFilterToMap('brand', 'eavatt.value');
        $this->addFilterToMap('sku', 'main_table.sku');
        $this->addFilterToMap('name', 'main_table.name');

        //$this->_modelTempdataFactory = $modelTempdataFactory;
        //$this->authSession = $authSession;

    }

    public function filterOrder()
    {

    $catalog_product_entity_table = $this->getTable("catalog_product_entity");
    $catalog_product_entity_inttable = $this->getTable("catalog_product_entity_int");
    $eav_attributeoptionvalue = $this->getTable("eav_attribute_option_value");
    $sales_order = $this->getTable("sales_order");
    $sales_order_address = $this->getTable("sales_order_address");


    $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('cpe' =>$catalog_product_entity_table), 'main_table.product_id = cpe.entity_id')
    ->columns(array('sum_qty_ordered' => new \Zend_Db_Expr("SUM(main_table.qty_ordered)"), 'total_amount' => new \Zend_Db_Expr("SUM(main_table.base_row_total)")))
    ->joinLeft(array('cpei' =>$catalog_product_entity_inttable),'cpei.row_id= cpe.row_id 
      AND cpei.attribute_id = "83" AND cpei.store_id = 0')
    ->joinLeft(array('eavatt' =>$eav_attributeoptionvalue), 'eavatt.option_id= cpei.value',array('brand' => 'eavatt.value'))
    ->joinLeft(array('so' =>$sales_order), 'so.entity_id= main_table.order_id',array('status' => 'so.status'))
    ->joinLeft(array('soa' =>$sales_order_address), 'soa.parent_id= main_table.order_id AND soa.address_type = "shipping"',array('shippingcity' => 'soa.city'))
    ->group('cpe.entity_id');

    $this->getSelect()->where("cpe.sku IS NOT NULL");

    $authSession = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(\Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session::class);
    $username = $authSession->getUser()->getUsername();
    $TempdataModel = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create('Vendor\Module\Model\TempdataFactory')->create();


    $TempdataCollection = $TempdataModel->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('identifier','brandwisereport')->addFieldToFilter('data_1',$username);

    if($TempdataCollection->count()) {
        foreach ($TempdataCollection as $Tempdata){
            $datearray = explode('_',$Tempdata->getData2());
            $orderstatuses = $Tempdata->getData3();
            $brand = $Tempdata->getData4();
        }
        $orderstatusesarray = explode(',',$orderstatuses);
        $orderstatusesforquery = implode("','",$orderstatusesarray);


        $from  = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($datearray[0]));
        $to = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($datearray[1]));

        $this->getSelect()->where("main_table.created_at >= '".$from." 00:00:00'");
        $this->getSelect()->where("main_table.created_at <= '".$to." 23:59:59'");
        $this->getSelect()->where("so.status IN ('$orderstatusesforquery')");
        $this->getSelect()->where('eavatt.value LIKE "'.$brand.'"');
    }   
    else {
        $this->getSelect()->where("cpe.entity_id = 0");
    }       
    //echo $this->getSelect();
    //die;      
   }

}
?>
```

I added the filter form including all filter field in one of my `admin phtml` file. call that phtml file using module admin layout. After form submit, It store filter form data against each admin user in custom table by using admin controller which will be used during collection  loading against each admin user.

> My grid file is look like this

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Brandwisereport;

class Grid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{

    protected $_countTotals = true;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager
     */
    protected $moduleManager;

    /**
     * @var \Vendor\Module\Model\brandwisereportFactory
     */
    protected $_brandwisereportFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Vendor\Module\Model\Status
     */
    protected $_status;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper
     * @param \Vendor\Module\Model\brandwisereportFactory $brandwisereportFactory
     * @param \Vendor\Module\Model\Status $status
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager
     * @param array $data
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Vendor\Module\Model\BrandwisereportFactory $BrandwisereportFactory,
        \Vendor\Module\Model\Status $status,
        \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_brandwisereportFactory = $BrandwisereportFactory;
        $this->_status = $status;
        $this->moduleManager = $moduleManager;
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('postGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('item_id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(false);
        //$this->setVarNameFilter('post_filter');
        $this->setFilterVisibility(false);
        //$this->buttonList->remove('selectall');
        //$this->buttonList->remove('save'); 
        //$this->buttonList->remove('reset');
        //$this->_removeButton('selectall');    
        //$this->buttonList->remove('delete'); 
    }

    public function getTotals()
    {
        $totals = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject;
        $fields = array(
            'sum_qty_ordered' => 0,
            'base_price' => 0,
            'total_amount' => 0
        );
        foreach ($this->getCollection() as $item) {
            foreach($fields as $field=>$value){
                    $fields[$field] += $item->getData($field);
            }
        }
        $fields['name']='Totals';
        $totals->setData($fields);
        return $totals;
    }


    /**
     * @return $this
     */ 
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_brandwisereportFactory->create()->getCollection();

        /********************** This code will apply filter on grid collection *****/
        $collection->filterOrder();

        $this->setCollection($collection);

        parent::_prepareCollection();

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            'brand',
            [
                'header' => __('Brand'),
                'index' => 'brand',
                'filter' => false
            ]
        );



                $this->addColumn(
                    'sku',
                    [
                        'header' => __('SKU'),
                        'index' => 'sku',
                        'filter' => false
                    ]
                );

                $this->addColumn(
                    'name',
                    [
                        'header' => __('Name'),
                        'index' => 'name',
                        'filter' => false
                    ]
                );

                $this->addColumn(
                    'sum_qty_ordered',
                    [
                        'header' => __('Sold Count'),
                        'type' => 'number',
                        'index' => 'sum_qty_ordered',
                        'filter' => false
                    ]
                );

                $this->addColumn(
                    'base_price',
                    [
                        'header' => __('Unit Price'),
                        'type' => 'currency',
                        'index' => 'base_price',
                        'filter' => false
                    ]
                );

                $this->addColumn(
                    'total_amount',
                    [
                        'header' => __('Total Amount'),
                        'type' => 'currency',
                        'index' => 'total_amount',
                        'filter' => false,
                        'format' => true
                    ]
                );

                $this->addColumn('action', array(
                    'header' => __('Action'),
                    'width' => '100',
                    'type' => 'action',
                    'getter' => 'getProductId',
                    'actions' => array(
                        array(
                            'caption' => __('View'),
                            'url' => array('base' => 'catalog/product/edit'),
                            'target'=>'_blank',
                            'field' => 'id'
                        )
                    ),
                    'renderer'  => 'Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Brandwisereport\Edit\Tab\Renderer\Brandwiseviewaction',
                    'filter' => false,
                    'sortable' => false,
                    'index' => 'id',
                    'is_system' => true,
                ));


           $this->addExportType($this->getUrl('module/*/exportCsv', ['_current' => true]),__('CSV'));
           $this->addExportType($this->getUrl('module/*/exportExcel', ['_current' => true]),__('Excel XML'));

        $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('grid.bottom.links');
        if ($block) {
            $this->setChild('grid.bottom.links', $block);
        }

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }



    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('module/*/index', ['_current' => true]);
    }

    /**
     * @param \Vendor\Module\Model\brandwisereport|\Magento\Framework\Object $row
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return '#';
    }
}
```

I don't know whether it is best practice or not but it worked at my end. I hope this will help others though I am still looking for best practice in order to make custom report just like default magento report.

Comment: hi @Mumammad, can you share the complete module, do we need to create any aggregate tables?

Comment: Good For Collection getting!!! If you can add all thing by step it would be great help for others too!!!

Comment: Muhammad Hasham, if possible can you please share this module via git to better understand it all and how this works. I'm working on similar task and need to build report from my custom tables.

Comment: May i get full code for this module

Answer (score 8):

I had created custom report for one project. I have created sample code with needed file and uploaded on github.

You can look at below URL.
https://github.com/yash7690/magento2-customreport

Comment: let me check this then I will get back to you

Comment: No it is not working. Though it will add the filter but may be your code is incomplete because I didn't find the target action controller of filter form in your code. I also made the custom report by using same approach by storing filter data in database tables and used in collection file as I mentioned in comments. So I don't think so this should be the best practice like magento 2 default report.

Comment: I have checked this code before posting the comment and it worked for me. So even if you freshly install extension, it should work. I have also checked magento sales report and it is using the same approach to save data in aggregate table. It is really strange that it is not working for you. Anyways good luck.

Comment: It is not working at my end. I tell you some of reasons in my above comment. Forget about whether it is working or not just tell me the detail working flow of your module in answer like explain each parts of your code including models, block, plugin, database tables and controller why you add them and what is that particular part working. I still mark it correct and it also helps others as well. Quick guide how anyone use your custom report?

Comment: Thanks Yash Shah for the time your have taken in this question. +1 for that

Comment: Thank u too ...

Comment: @YashShah,How to hide the filter columns, Period and empty rows? I need to show only From and To..

Comment: @YashShah, I need to show custom collection..

Comment: @MuhammadHasham, Is it worked for you, I have same requirement where i need to load the custom collection.

Comment: @jafarpinjar, yes you may use my code and it will work. You will get the understanding of code within an hour or 2. Also there is a readme file in module for quick guidline. Just be careful with renaming vendor, module, controller etc names. Where i have used only first letter capital, do not use camel case in that.

Comment: @YashShah, I have to create a Report for Category info, like The grid should have Meta title, Meta description and other category info, can we use this module?

Comment: @jafarpinjar, This is for reports and not for showing custom information. In report, the major part is to use the group by clause. In your case, if you are showing meta information, by what bases, it will be group by ?